# Post Deployment Tests

Tags: .net, deployment, jenkins, msbuild, configuration-files

I am working on application that has got lot many configurations.

These configuration are like

- WebRefrence url to other internal apps
- Folders to keep separate files for each feature
- paths to third party exes

What should be used to create deployment tests

- nunit
- mstest
- anything else

such that it checks

- if it can access urls,
- folders exist and no permission issue,
- files are available and not deleted?

plan to run post deployment of app using msbuild / jenkins job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is not straight forward but from what I can think here is ,
you need to start writing your own custom module to do the validation.

first of all use regex to differentiate between  folder, url, and file value.

once identified folder and files are easy to detect with Directory and File .Exist

for url use the web connect method, get the status code and confirm that urls is accessible.
make sure you use try catch , all 500 will raise exception.

once done you can write plugin to build msbuild custom action or run via jenkins.